# How to create a dummy akka Httpresponse with a delay?

Tags: scala, unit-testing, routes, akka-http

As we can create a dummy httpresponse with `HttpResponse`

But it doesn't create any delay in the response, Is there a way to add a delay into it?

Comment: Why not add a `Thread.sleep(delay in ms)` before send the response?

Answer (score 1):

Maby somethink like this? Based on [akka.pattern.after](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/futures.html).
Test with 10s delay -> http://localhost:9000/example?delay=10000

```
object Main extends App with Directives {

  implicit val system: ActorSystem = ActorSystem()

  val routes: Route = {
    (get & path("example")) {
      parameter("delay".as[Int]) { delay =>
        complete {
          akka.pattern.after(delay.millis) {
            Future.successful(response(delay))
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

  def response(delay: Int): HttpResponse = {
    HttpResponse(
      StatusCodes.OK,
      entity = HttpEntity(
    ContentTypes.`text/html(UTF-8)`,
    s"""
       |<html>
       | <body>
       |  Example request with delay $delay
       | </body>
       |</html>
       |""".stripMargin
      )
    )
  }

  val (host, port) = ("localhost", 9000)

  Http().newServerAt(host, port).bind(routes)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can and without Thread.sleep. Because it blocks the thread and if you need to simulate a service that is under a lot of requests it is not a good option. Check this old implementation, maybe it can help: https://github.com/EmiCareOfCell44/http-retarder

Comment: but you use the `akka.pattern.ask` here (https://github.com/EmiCareOfCell44/http-retarder/blob/master/src/main/scala/io/ecocell44/Router.scala#L44) and afaik it is blocking. So it is the same of having a simple `HttpResponse` that has a long computation inside it. Isn't it?

Comment: ask pattern creates a Future waiting for the response but it does not block the whole thread. Thread.Sleep blocks the whole thread where another futures and actors are being executed

Comment: I know, so you just need to wrap the `HttpResponse` inside a `Future` and you do a long computation there. But the `GET` or `POST` of a `HttpResponse` is still blocking. In other words, it is not necessary to use the `akka.pattern.ask` to do that.

Comment: Yes, you contain that request inside a future and with a timeout